# Calcular distancia entre dois pontos em C++ utilzando struct

Tags: c++, struct

Estou com dificuldades para imprimir o resultado, mas antes disso não esta realizado calculo por ser tipo novo criado pela `struct` ele não calcula pois pede tipo `double`

segue o código

```
#include <iostream>



using namespace std;

 struct Ponto{
 float x;
 float y;
 float d;

 }; 
void LerRetangulo(Ponto ret[], int tam)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<tam;i++)
    {
        cout <<"digite coordenadas x e y  "<<i+1 <<endl;
        cin >> ret[i].x>>ret[i].y;
    }
}

void CalcDistancia(Ponto ret[], int tam ){ 
   float h
        for(int i = 0; i<tam;i++)
    {
    h = sqrt(pow ( ret[i].x,2) + pow ( ret[i].y,2)); // problema aqui !!!!  

    }

}
 /*
aqui eu estava fazendo alguns teste 
void imprimir(?,int tam){
    for (int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<< "A distancia = "<<? <<endl;
    }

    */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 Ponto retangulo[4];
LerRetangulo(retangulo,4);
 CalcDistancia(retangulo,4);
 //imprimir(?,4); duvida aqui !!!!!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que é este `d` na estrutura `Ponto`? Seria a distância? Porque um ponto teria uma distância? Você sabe que seu código nem compila? Ele está cheio de erro até de sintaxe, além de estar sem um padrão. Pode parecer bobagem mas organizar o código ajuda entender melhor o que está fazendo e achar erros bobos. Vou ver se consigo responder mas preciso saber se `d`tem alguma função real na estrutura. E que distância deve ser calculada? Distância entre o que? Tem 4 pontos. Normalmente se calcula a distância entre 2 pontos.

Comment: Tem erros de sintaxe, vários. Você nunca tentou compilar esse programa. Responde o resto que eu perguntei, não tem como resolver o problema da forma como você está fazendo. O seu código não está resolvendo um problema plausível. Então descreva o problema, qual é o resultado que se quer chegar. Você quer calcular o perímetro de um polígono? Porque precisa da distância dentro do ponto? E se é o perímetro, o que distância te a ver com isto?

Comment: O @bigown tem razão, não faz sentido calcular a distância para um ponto. A distância [é entre dois pontos](http://www.brasilescola.com/matematica/distancia-entre-dois-pontos.htm). De todas as formas, pela sua descrição o erro é que a função `sqrt` [espera um tipo `double`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/) e você está usando `float`. Troque o tipo para `double` na definição na estrutura e teste novamente, por favor.

Comment: Não adianta você ficar arrumando um errinho e deixar os outros, você precisa explicar o problema que você está tentando resolver. Você quer calcular o perímetro ou quer calcular o tamanho da hipotenusa? Neste caso precisaria garantir que é um retângulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não entendi qual é o problema que está sendo resolvido e depois de várias tentativas não consegui uma informação melhor. Então vou resolver os problemas que estão claramente demonstrados na pergunta. Certamente este código não apresenta o resultado desejado mas pelo menos ele está mais fácil de ler e entender o que está fazendo, ele compila e está com os tipos certos. Com certeza ele precisa ser modificado para resolver um problema real, mas o que deu para entender está funcionando. Eu ainda posso melhorar se o problema for explicado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

 struct Ponto{
    float x;
    float y;
 }; 
void LerRetangulo(Ponto ret[], int tam) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        cout << "digite coordenadas x e y  do ponto " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> ret[i].x >> ret[i].y;
    }
}

double CalcDistancia(Ponto ret[], int tam) {
    double distancia = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        distancia += sqrt(pow(ret[i].x, 2) + pow(ret[i].y, 2));
    }
    return distancia;
}

void imprimir(double distancia, Ponto ret[], int tam) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        cout << "Ponto " << i << " = " << ret[i].x << ", " << ret[i].y <<endl;
    }
    cout << "Distância = " << distancia << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Ponto retangulo[4];
    LerRetangulo(retangulo, 4);
    imprimir(CalcDistancia(retangulo, 4), retangulo, 4);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qITYjE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tvvtnouu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/CalcDistance.cpp).